# AWS Web server not working even with the right security group setting

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created a web server in my ec2 instance, with this script

in the user data

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo su
yum install -y httpd.x86_64
systemctl start httpd.service
systemctl enable httpd.service
echo "Hello world from $(hostname -f)"> /var/www/html/index.html
```

The problem is if I open the public IP in the browser, it won't work  it shows "This site can’t be reached"

even if I made all traffic allowed still it won't work, what seems to be the problem ?!

I tried more than 10 instances and still the same issues

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czpsA.png)

Comment: Does the vpc have a route to an internet gateway?

Comment: I am new to AWS , I am using EC2 instance , don't know a thing about  "route to an internet gateway" cloud you please provided me with a info source for that

Comment: Check this out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html

Comment: Have you also confirmed apache is installed and running after confirming you have access to internet(route to internet gateway)?